# PermanentTaskFailure: No module named X

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm trying to use the deferred extension for GAE to execute a task in a backend instance. It works locally using the dev server but when I deploy my app to Google and test the app, it fails with the following error:

```
Permanent failure attempting to execute task
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/deferred/deferred.py", line 309, in post
    self.run_from_request()
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/deferred/deferred.py", line 304, in run_from_request
    run(self.request.body)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/deferred/deferred.py", line 144, in run
    raise PermanentTaskFailure(e)
PermanentTaskFailure: No module named async
```

The async module contains the function which is meant to be deferred. It's in the same directory as the module which handles the requests.

I've searched around on SO and none of the other similar questions have answers that help. I'm not doing any PYTHONPATH manipulation. My deferred function is defined in a separate module (async) from the module containing the request handlers.

Project source can be viewed at https://github.com/lokyst/ffxivcraftopt. webapi.py contains the request handlers. SolverHandler.post calls queueTask in the async module, which sets up the task and then calls defer.

Comment: Have you deployed the code to 'solverbackend'?

Comment: That was it! Thank you! Propose it as an answer and I'll accept it. :)

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you did to solve it?  I also am not using path manipulation, but am getting the same error.

Comment: I had forgotten to deploy the backend in addition to the main app.